# Check if email already exist in database

Tags: python, django, forms

In my django account app I want to check if inputed email exist in database (basic django db.sqlite3).

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label='Hasło', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Powtórz hasło', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'email')

    def clean_password2(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data



        if cd['password'] != cd['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Hasła nie są identyczne.')

        return cd['password2']
```

**views.py:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid():
            # Creating new user object, without saving in database
            new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)

            # Setting new password
            new_user.set_password(
                user_form.cleaned_data['password'])

            # Saving user object
            new_user.save()
            return render(request,
                          'account/register_done.html',
                          {'new_user': new_user})
    else:
        user_form = UserRegistrationForm()

    return render(request,
                  'account/register.html',
                 {'user_form': user_form})
```

Now when i enter the same email for another user, form creates that user.

I think is it possible to make this in that way?
1). make email as variable like password and password2
2). remove email from meta
3). create method clean_email() with checking if email exist in db if not raise error

I don't know how to get to emails in db

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You need to set a unique constraint in the db schema, so that each email can only be used once, then catch the db error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below `is_valid():` in your `views.py` do this

```
if user_form.is_valid():
    new_user = user_form.save(commit=False)
    email=user_form.cleaned_data['email']
    if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        //the rest of your code 
    else:
       //some error message
```

This ensures that a new user is only created if they do not already exist.

If you working on an app that requires a username, email, and password length of x(in this case 8), then do this.

```
if not User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
    if not User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        if len(password) < 8:
            // some error message alert 
            return('register') // the same page
        //continue with the rest of your code
        .....
    return ('login-page')
return('register') the same page
```

If this solves your issue please don't forget to accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. It helps me, I did it! But i do it in forms.py instead of views.py. Your QuerySet helped me a lot